# Error when using handlers Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.os.Handler.sendMessage

Tags: android, handler, sendmessage

I am getting a

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.os.Handler.sendMessage(android.os.Message)' on a null object reference at com.example.android.slidenerd180handler.MainActivity$MyThread.run(MainActivity.java:37)
```

I am not sure why it is not working, I did everything that it said in this tutorial video on youtube for android handler, but it still doesn't work.

the line 37 is `handler.sendMessage(message);`

```
    class MyThread implements Runnable {


    @Override
    public void run() {
        for(int i =0;i<100;i++){
            Message message = Message.obtain();
            message.arg1=i;
            handler.sendMessage(message);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
```

Comment: did you initialize your declared and initialized your handler object?

Comment: Please show a complete example. You need to show all variable declarations and matching curly braces.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)

Answer (score 1):

It does not work if you do not make sure that the `Handler` is initialized before you send a message.

For that, you can make your thread sleep for a few ms (like 2 ms) before sending the message. The fact is that when the `UIThread` is running `thread.start()`, the secondary thread (the one implementing `Runnable`) starts.

The loop in the `run()` method starts and the instruction `handler.sendMessage(message)` is executed by the  secondary thread before the instruction `handler = new Handler()` can be read by the `UIThread`.

You can't be sure that it will always happens this way so you have to make sure the `Handler` is initialized first. You can put `Thread.sleep(100);` into the `run()` section of the secondary thread.

Comment: Don't write things like "Leave a like" please, it is denigrating to the purpose of the site

Answer (score 0):

This error means that you are trying to send a message that is null. In other words, the message is empty. Check where you are obtaining the message and make sure that there is not a chance that the message will be null.

Before sending the message, you should add an if statement. Try replacing your code with this:

```
class MyThread implements Runnable {

@Override
public void run() {
    for(int i =0;i<100;i++){
        Message message = Message.obtain();
        if(message != null){
            message.arg1=i;
            handler.sendMessage(message);
        }
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You are starting MyThread before handler is initialized(I guess from onCreate() of activity). Initialize handler before it MyThread  executes.